# Node.js: Error trying to use shell command that interacts with files

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am trying to use `pngquant` after I have uploaded images to my Node.js application.

I am running the following code after upload:

```
if (pngFiles.length) {
    console.log('PNG Files Ready for Processing: ', pngFiles);

    pngFiles.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file);
        exec('pngquant --force ' + file, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
        });
    });
}
```

But end up with the following error:

```
{ [Error: Command failed:   error: cannot open     /Users/nfento/Projects/jamdeo/public/uploads/mytestcontrollers/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-    ABF90A23D9F5/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-ABF90A23D9F5_7_tablet.png for reading
] killed: false, code: 2, signal: null } '' '  error: cannot open /Users/nfento/Projects/jamdeo/public/uploads/mytestcontrollers/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-ABF90A23D9F5/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-ABF90A23D9F5_7_tablet.png for reading\n'
```

For every file, if I go into the shell and run

```
`pngquant /Users/nfento/Projects/jamdeo/public/uploads/mytestcontrollers/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-ABF90A23D9F5/92614D43-A55A-4456-9663-ABF90A23D9F5_7_tablet.png`
```

I get a success message, what am I doing wrong here? Does my application need additional access?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to check when you get the error `cannot open <PATH> for reading` is check the filesystem permissions including owner, group, mode, and all parent directories. Is your node code running as the same user as when you run the command manually in the shell?

Other note probably not your issue, but in general, be really careful when building up a string to be passed to `exec` as it is extremely easy to allow bugs and big security vulnerabilities via this type of code. So first, try quoting your file path so if you had a path with a space in it, for example, your code would still work correctly.

```
exec("pngquant --force '" + file + "'", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
```